# Why am I getting different responses on the same Curl request?

Tags: ssl, web-scraping, curl, certificate

I have two vps, when I do `curl --verbose https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005004830406404.html`

different things happen, on a server it returns the response correctly with the following header

https://hastebin.com/onifayedam.yaml

but on the other server, newly configured it returns 404 with the following header

https://hastebin.com/okibilihir.php-template

I have tried to reinstall the certificates, even to reinstall the operating system from 0 without any result.
I would be grateful for any help or recommendation.

Comment: It is considered polite to include all the necessary details *in the question* and not link to external sites (that will timeout and vanish before this question does).

Comment: Thanks for answering, and sorry for putting external links, in the links are the request header, when I put it directly here, it told me it was spam